# pattern for matching a filepath

Tags: regex, grep

Can you please tell me the grep pattern for matching the following filepath:

> ../any_directoryname/filename.txt

I only know the filename. The `any_directoryname` keeps on changing.

Thanks in advance,

Regards

John

Comment: what u want to retrieve?? will u please paste any example with desired output

Comment: @diEcho Thanks for you attention. I need  output like ../directory1/test.txt ../superdirectory/test.txt

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this:

```
\.\./[^/]+/filename.txt
```

This assumes only one directory. If it can be more than that, try

```
\.\./[^\r\n]+/filename.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

try this regex

```
^\.\.\/[\w]+\/[\w\.]+$
```

Comment: `_` does not need escaping and is already included in `\w`. `.` does within a character class also not need to be escaped. The OP does know the filename so it should end with `filename\.txt$`, your last part matches for example also "........"

Comment: Thanks Abhishek for your valuable time. But it didn't gave me any output.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the filename and want to extract the path from the string, use

```
str_replace('/filename.txt', '', $full_path);
```

A regex is not reliable if both file and path vary (you can only find out if something is a file or directory using filesystem commands, name checking is not going to tell you that), and if one of the two doesn't vary, you don't need a regex at all.

Comment: Thanks David. I am using Grep [WinGrep] to find the path

Answer (score 0):

How about...

(A Perl answer...)

For a given path/filename in the form of:

```
$fullPath = /dir/dir/dir/filename

($path, $file) = $fullPath =~ m/(^\/.*\/)(\S+$)/;
```

That puts

```
$path = /dir/dir/dir/...
$file = filename
```